# Dynamic form creation-AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

ive run into a problem that I was hoping you could help me out with.  Basically I am trying to create a dynamic form creation page using AngularJS and bootstrap (just a simple one).  I have successfully created the buttons which when clicked create the form, and he input, however when I attempt to type anything into the text inputs im getting an error "Cannot set property 'id1' of undefined".  What I basically do is via clicking the buttons I put together a JSON string which I then use angulars ng-repeat to loop through the contents of the created JSON to create the inputs etc on screen.  The code can be seen below:

Controller code(functions map to the corresponding button):

```
$scope.createRow = function(){
            $scope.newForm.sections[0].rows.push({"attribute": "", "properties":[]});
        };

$scope.createInput = function(){
            $scope.newForm.sections[0].rows[0].properties.push({"id":"id1", "input": "text"});
        }
```

html code:

```
               <section  id="test" ng-repeat="property in row.properties">

                    <div class="{{property.inputDivCss || 'col-md-8'}}">
                        <input
                                class="{{property.inputClass}}"
                                type="{{property.type}}"
                                placeholder="{{property.placeholder}}"
                                ng-model="enrollmentForm.properties[property.id]"
                                ng-required="property.required"
                                name="{{property.id}}"
                                value="{{property.value}}"
                                ng-pattern="{{property.pattern}}"
                                />
                    </div>

                </section>
```

As I say, When I click the corresponding button which calls createInput the text box is displayed and everything looks fine.  It only when I attempt to type in the text box that I get an error "Cannot set property 'id1' of undefined".  Im probably doing something silly or just forgetting to initialise something but for the life of me I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any help I may get.

Comment: How/where do you define `enrollmentForm`?

Comment: When you get input, F12 your browser - get you input html - paste it here. then we might help you out.

Comment: i think it's because your ng-model isn't initialize yet, you have to initialize it before, try ng-init in template or make a new scope in function

Comment: Ahh guys,  Thats brilliant, thank you, I knew it was something silly.  It was down to the fact that I hadn't defined enrollmentForm hence my ng-model was initialized as you suggested.  Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this: [angular-dynamic-form](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms)
and also [angular-formly](http://nimbly.github.io/angular-formly/#!/)

to solve your problem, initialize properties

```
enrollmentForm.properties = {};
```